# Accounts inexplicably removed from "Accounts & sync"

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, accounts

I'm running CyanogenMod 7.1.0 on my HTC Desire. I have a few accounts added in "Accounts & Sync" (Last.fm, Facebook, Skype, Soundcloud, etc.), but on several occasions all of them (except Google) got deleted, and I had to log in again in all of them using the respective applications. This could be quite annoying, but fortunately happens only every few days or so.

I can't quite understand why it happens and what causes it. I have some suspicion it might be related to the fact I don't have much space on the device (Desire notoriously has ridiculously little internal storage) -- although I always keep it above the "Low space" warning (which is something like 15 MB).

Is this a known problem? What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Did you install these apps to the sdcard?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik: I did, actually. But the accounts disappear only rarely, sometimes week pass between occasions. But you might be right that it could have something to do with SD card mounting. I need to experiment to confirm

Comment: So did you have any success? AFAIR providing a sync-account belongs to the criteria for apps one should not move to SD, so I'm pretty sure this is related. If you found the answer, feel free to place it in an answer and accept it yourself -- so other users affected by the same problem can find it ;)

Answer (score 1):

After some months of additional observation, I'm pretty certain that the accounts disappear when the free internal space gets low, usually when I'm down to 12 MB or so. Presumably, Android tries to free up some internal space occupied by app data, and the accounts seem to be the first to go.

Due to the low internal storage, I have moved all apps to the external storage, so this might as well be a factor, as Izzy mentions in the comments.